# Tableau Extract refresh through API call from python. Getting unauthorized access (401002 response)

Tags: api, tableau-api

we are working on setting up tableau extract refresh through API invocation. We are using Personal access tokens from tableau for authentication. While we are able to establish the communication and are able to retrieve details on tableau site, we get a 401002 response when we try for extract refresh. Is there a need for an additional privilege to the access token to set the extract refresh.
Any pointers on this would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the user whose PAT you're using is the **owner** of the workbook (and hence the extraction schedule). If not, the extraction request will fail. Alternatively, if the user cannot be the owner, they must be server administrators or site administrators on your Tableau server.
2. Also make sure you already have a schedule for the extract refresh. If one doesn't exist, you can create it with the Create Schedule method (with the API this can only be done by server administrators, on the browser the owner of the workbook can do this).
3. From the Tableau API docs, also note that "A REST request to start a refresh task will fail if the task has been put in the task queue in any of these ways, or is already in progress". This might also be one reason why it fails.